# Teniendo JDK es necesário aún tener JRE para ejecutar ciertos programas ?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Hola resulta que tengo instalado en mi equipo el JDK el cual contiene tambien el JRE, pero al intetar ejecutar ciertos programas para elaborar una base de datos (Por ejemolo:LibreOffice Data Base) me sale un pop up diciendo que es necesario tener JRE lo cual no entiendo ya que el JDK ya tiene consigo el JRE. Y ademas no puedo ni siquiera abrir data base.

Comment: Al instalar el JDK, ¿has añadido la carpeta bin al Path? Prueba a abrir una consola y ejecutar el comando java -version

Answer (score 1):

Es muy posible que el JRE de tu JDK no esté "registrado" en tu equipo. Es decir, al usar el JDK, éste usará el JRE interno, pero para el resto de tus aplicaciones no existe porque durante la instalación no se añadió a la variable de entorno `path`. Asegúrate de que java.exe (en windows) o el fichero ejecutable java (en GNU/Linux) está en el path (desde cualquier directorio deberías poder ejecutar `java --version` y obtener la salida correcta).

Nota: quizá te interese instalar un JRE aparte, que se vaya actualizando automáticamente (el JDK no lo hace), para el uso "normal" de tus aplicaciones. Además esto te permitiría tener el JDK 8 y JRE 9 (o viceversa, aunque las aplicaciones empresariales o "de servidor" suelen ser más conservadoras en cuestión de novedades)